# Generate a random boolean with given probability

Tags: java, simulated-annealing, stochastic

I am writing java code to solve a problem with simulated annealing method. I need a method to generate a random `true` only with probability exp(a/b) where `a` and `b` are given parameters.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that the distribution must be in accordance to `f = exp(a/b)`, with f being the density funcion, or that `f = exp(a/b)` is the actual distribution?

Comment: See [my source code](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/localsearch/decider/acceptor/simulatedannealing/SimulatedAnnealingAcceptor.java#L88): `double acceptChance = Math.exp(-moveScoreDifference / temperature); if (random.nextDouble() < acceptChance) {...}`

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that `a/b` is the percentage probability of returning true:

```
public boolean exp(double probabilityTrue)
{
    return Math.random() >= 1.0 - probabilityTrue;
}
```

Comment: if you are only using `probability_true` then you can remove the `probability_false` method parameter and also the return statement can be shortened to `return (Math.Random() * 100) > probability_true;` since the evaluation of that statement results in a true or false being returned anyway.

Comment: @kstandell I edited the question. The correct form is exp(a/b). The probability of true outcomes is exp(a/b). However, I can customize it for my case. Thanks